# How to match multi-line strings in Ruby using Regular Expressions to be used in an Inverted Index?

Tags: ruby, regex, inverted-index

Assignment instructions: http://pastebin.com/pxJS4gfR

**Objective:** Take a collection of documents and generate its inverted index.

**My plan**

1. Grab the relevant strings from the collections file
2. Tokenize them and place them into a Hash to be used later.

I am using the following regular expression `\.I(.*?)\.B\m` to grab the text needed from a collections file as shown here: http://rubular.com/r/mOpfuvRT12

Edit: I have used `mudasobwa`'s suggestion

```
content = File.read('test.txt')
# deal with content
content.scan(/\.T(.*?)\.B/m) { |mtch| 
  puts mtch 
}
```

This grabs the necessary text I need however I need to place the grabbed text into a Hash to be used later and I am not sure how to work with the `String.scan/regex/` because it returns an Array of Arrays.

I am basically trying to replicate this example:

```
puts "Enter something: "
text = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each do |word|
    frequencies[word] += 1
end
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |k, v| v }
frequencies.reverse!
frequencies.each do |word, freq|
    puts word + " " + freq.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to read the file line by line. In such a case `/m` multiline modifier makes no sense. You are to read the entire file and then parse it for whatever you want:

```
content = File.read('test.txt')
content.scan(/\.T(.*?)\.B/m) { |mtch| 
  puts mtch 
}
```

**UPD**
To put the scan results to hash as in the example you need either `flatten` method of an array:

```
content = File.read('test.txt')
# flatten the array                  ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
words = content.scan(/\.T(.*?)\.B/m).flatten
words.each …
```

or block within `scan` method:

```
content = File.read('test.txt')
freqs = {}
content.scan(/\.T(.*?)\.B/m) { |mtch| 
  (freqs[mtch] ||= 0) += 1 
}
…
```

**UPD2** To `split` the resulting array of sentenses to array of words:

```
arr = ["Preliminary Report International", "Fingers or Fists"]   
arr.map {|e| e.split(' ')}.flatten.map(&:downcase)
# ⇒  ["preliminary", "report", "international", "fingers", "or", "fists"]
```

Here first `map` iterates array elements and transforms them to arrays of splitten words, `flatten` produces plain array from yielded array of arrays, and, finally, `downcase` is here because you’ve requested the downcased words in your example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I assign a variable 'stuff' to content.scan(/regex/), stuff would be an Array of Arrays correct where the elements are long-sentences? What I was wondering is there a way to .split(" ") them up like you would a string? i.e. into smaller words?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your needs now. Would you provide the desired output?

Comment: That's almost close to what I need, the array content's elements just need to split up from: ["Preliminary Report International", "Fingers or Fists"] into ["preliminary", "report", "international", "fingers", "or", "fists"]. Thank you so much for your help thus far, it's late so I'm going to turn in. I spent too many hours trying to solve this.

Comment: Thank you so much, this should allow me to build from your example. I did not know about `Array.map` or `flatten` from my lessons.

Comment: Well, you are welcome. I suggest you to throw a glance at the class documentation (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html) every time you use some not-well-known-for-you class. Ruby has methods for almost anything in the universe. Anyway, glad to help.